# How to copy vendor folder without having not found problem

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, composer-php, virtualenv

I am using `composer` for my project and the entire project (even the `vendor` folder) is under git version control.
I know it may seem like a false action but I am in bandwidth deficit and I want to lower my bandwidth usage so I use this method to just copy the `vendor` folder.
When I push to to another repository and try to run `php main.php` from there It says that can not find the classes that I am using there.

I have managed to solve this problem by removing the whole `vendor` folder and re running `composer i` but it is not the behavior that I want. I want low bandwidth usage, I want to not wait for package installation.

I am using the same method for `virtualenv` of python apps and there is the same problem but that problem can be solved by just running `virtualenv venv/` again so it corrects the new paths for the **copied** environment. How can I achieve the same behavior with `composer`? I dont see any info or command that can help me doing this.

Thanks in advance folks :)

Comment: What is the version of your composer? Have you copied completed "Vendor" folder?

Comment: try composer dump-autoload in shell after you pull from git

Comment: @UsamaAyaz yeah in my local repository I hit `composer i` and the complete `vendor` folder gets created. Then I push the whole files (`vendor/` + my php files) to remote. I want to be able to correct that `vendor` folder rather than installing it from `composer.json` again.

Comment: Yeah i fully understood your requirement that is to keep the vendor folder in VCS and you don't want to install the dependencies again. You should try "composer dump-autoload" that will regenerate the autoload file without download the dependencies agains.

Comment: I tried that but it says `Generated autoload files containing 0 classes` and the problem is still there.

Comment: Is `vender/composer` folder a folder that is generated by the `composer` itself?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
All you need to do is to remove one file and one folder:

```
rm -rf vendor/composer;
rm vendor/autoload.php;
```

Then run `composer i` and it will recreate the removed `composer` folder again and corrects the autoload files.

Have a nice day.

Comment: In this case you would have to reinstall the packages again on the contrary you have asked for option other than this.

Comment: No it will not download. I have tested it with internet connection disabled. It just checks that some particular dependency exists and will not download it again. Just checks it. BTW thanks for your time.